# How can I move/reposition the title label + down arrow in a Cocoa Document based application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, nsdocument

My aim is to reposition the combination of title label and dropdown (that appear automatically in the titlebar of a document based app) against the right hand side of the window instead of centred.

An alternative: I could set the titlebar to hidden and place a label and button in a view directly beneath the titlebar - but under my direct control. In this instance, what classes should I use for the label and down arrow button to reuse as much of the automatic functionality from Cocoa document based apps?

===

The built-in functionality includes:
1. updating the name of the label/button once it has been saved and managing future edits...
2. being aware of the document being dirty (unsaved state)
etc...